# How to correctly call python function from lldb

Tags: python, macos, lldb

I have this simple python script:

```
#~/.lldb/scripts/fprint.py

import lldb

def fprint(filePath, text):
    with open(filePath,'a') as f: f.write(text)

def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    debugger.HandleCommand('command script add -f fprint.fprint fprint')
    print '"fprint(filePath, text)" command is here!'
```

Which I declare in `~/.lldbinit`.

When trying to call it from `lldb` I get this weird error:

> % lldb
>   "fprint(filePath, text)" command is here!
>   (lldb) fprint 'tmp.txt' 'Hello World!'
>   TypeError: fprint() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
>   (lldb)

So, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing more than just calling a Python function, you are defining a Python backed lldb command-line command.  That has a few more requirements, in particular, the Python function implementing the LLDB command must have the right signature.  See the section [*Create a new lldb command using a Python function* in the LLDB docs](http://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#create-a-new-lldb-command-using-a-python-function) for more details.

Note, if you just want to call a Python function using lldb's embedded Python interpreter, you can do that with the "script" command:

```
(lldb) script fprint("tmp.txt", "Hello world")
```